# How do I make a dynamic sticky toolbar without weird scroll glitch when page is slightly longer than page height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code to move a toolbar that is below a header to stick to the top of the viewport when scrolling down. The problem is when the height of the content is slightly higher than the viewport. When you attempt to scroll to the bottom, it bounces back up to just above the end of the content with a weird visual glitch. It probably has to do with the fact that when the 'sticky' class is added, it increases the height of the page, but I'm not sure how to remedy it.

Javascript/JQuery:

```
var enableSticky = () => {
    let headerHeight = $('.toolbar').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(() => {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > headerHeight) {
            $('.toolbar').addClass('sticky');
        } else {
            $('.toolbar').removeClass('sticky');
        }
    });
};
```

CSS:

```
.toolbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 84px;
    position: relative;
}

.toolbar.sticky {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    margin-bottom: -84px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="bcmMain" style="display: block;">
<h1 id="event-title"><span class="view-table-value" data-field-name="mopId">927</span> - <span class="view-table-value" data-field-name="subject">Sample Subject</span></h1>
    <div class="toolbar">
        <div class="status-toolbar-group toolbar-group">
            <a class="button" id="level-button">Level <span class="view-table-value" data-field-name="level">3</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="toolbar-group">
            <a class="button" id="status-button">Status: <span class="view-table-value" data-field-name="status">complete</span></a>
            <a class="button" id="pending-button">Mark Pending</a>
        </div>
        <div class="edit-toolbar-group toolbar-group">
            <a class="button" id="submit-changes-button">Submit Changes</a>
            <a class="button" id="cancel-changes-button">Cancel Changes</a>
        </div>
        <div class="toolbar-group">
            <a class="button" id="edit-button">Edit</a>
            <a class="button" id="clone-button">Clone</a>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div id="edit-details">
        <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried doing  `if ($(window).scrollTop() > headerHeight + 100)` to see if allowing further scrolling before the it adds the sticky class, but it just changes the height at which the window is at when the glitch occurs.

What can I do to improve the code to get rid of this glitch?

EDIT: Added HTML. I tried to include just the relevant HTML, but let me know if anything else is needed. Thanks!

NOTE 1: This is embedded in a Confluence page. Confluence page header is hidden, but not the Confluence website header or the sidebar. See the below images to see what I'm talking about. Both images are at the top of the viewport at different scroll points.

[Image of Not Sticky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA8v4.png)

[Image of Sticky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQCTf.png)

NOTE 2: Not sure if this is important... data is pulled from a database via API to fill the fields on this page.

Comment: The first step you do is add some html along with it.

Comment: first you have to replace from let to var

Comment: here var is a global. Let can use only inside the function. And one mor thing you add html wrap also

Comment: Sorry about the lack of HTML. I included an HTML snippet, but as I explained in the notes, this is actually embedded in a Confluence page. See images for a reference.

Comment: As far as using `var` versus `let`, it's actually because it's embedded in a function . I updated the javascript to reflect this. At this time, this function is called automatically once everything is loaded but before the page is displayed to the user.

Let me know if you have any additional questions and thanks for following up!

Comment: Try to recreate the problem either in a StackOverflow Code Snippet or on jsfiddle.net or codepen.io or something and put a link in your question. Strip all irrelevant code, take the problem out of your Confluence page. Then we have something to work with, we can fiddle around with it and try to find a solution. (I know this seems like a lot of work, but that is exactly what anyone who would want to help you, would have to do. Only seems fair that you do most of the prep work. Also, there is a fair chance that in doing all that, you already find a solution yourself.)

Comment: Have you tried creating the same menu twice? Make one of them have position relative and scroll with the page and then have a second identical one with position absolute at the top. Make the z-index of whatever is above the "non-sticky" menu be a 3, the "sticky" menu a 2, and the rest of the page a z-index of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure I get what you mean, but I think you're referring to the 'bounce' of the content caused by removing the toolbar from the flow of the page.
The content always bounces the distance of the height of the toolbar regardless of the height of the content in relation to the viewport, but maybe it's more apparent then because you see the bottom of the content bounce as well as the top.

Anyway, if that *is* what you're referring to, I think this is your fix:

```
.toolbar.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
.toolbar.sticky + #edit-details {padding-top:84px;}
```

- I removed `z-index:5;` and `margin-bottom:-84px;` because they weren't doing anything.
- Instead I added the `.toolbar.sticky + #edit-details {padding-top:84px;}` rule.
  What this does is, it adds `padding-top` to the `#edit-details` that directly follows the `.toolbar.sticky` (that's what the `+` is for, [read about it here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)). In other words; the *padding-top* of the content is dependent on the toolbar having the *sticky* class.
  So when the `.sticky` class is added to the toolbar - and thereby `84px` is removed from the flow of the page (which caused the 'bounce') - that same `84px` is added again just before the content in the form of padding, causing the content to stay at exactly the same place.
  When the .`sticky` class is removed again, the padding is removed again too.
  *- The `padding-top` should have the same value as the toolbar `height`.*
- I also removed `position:relative;` from `.toolbar`, because again, it wasn't doing anything.

You can test it below in the code snippet, though it may be easier to test in the jsfiddle, because there you can adjust the height of the viewport.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let headerHeight = $('.toolbar').offset().top;
  
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > headerHeight) {
      $('.toolbar').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('.toolbar').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.toolbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
.toolbar.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
.toolbar.sticky + #edit-details {padding-top:25px;}

/*ONLY FOR VISUAL STYLING*/
.toolbar-group {margin-right:5px; float:left;}
.toolbar-group a {float:left; padding:1px;}
.toolbar-group .button {background:lightblue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bcmMain" style="display: block;">
  <h1 id="event-title"><span class="view-table-value" data-field-name="mopId">927</span> - <span class="view-table-value" data-field-name="subject">Sample Subject</span></h1>
  <div class="toolbar">
    <div class="status-toolbar-group toolbar-group">
      <a class="button" id="level-button">Level <span class="view-table-value" data-field-name="level">3</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="toolbar-group">
      <a class="button" id="status-button">Status: <span class="view-table-value" data-field-name="status">complete</span>|</a>
      <a class="button" id="pending-button">Mark Pending</a>
    </div>
    <div class="edit-toolbar-group toolbar-group">
      <a class="button" id="submit-changes-button">Submit|</a>
      <a class="button" id="cancel-changes-button">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    <div class="toolbar-group">
      <a class="button" id="edit-button">Edit|</a>
      <a class="button" id="clone-button">Clone</a>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div id="edit-details">
    content - first<br>content - second<br>content - third<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content - forelast<br>content - last<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nd9etLjy/1/**

*I added some CSS to style the toolbar, this is not important for functionality.

I also changed your arrow-functions to regular ones, because I couldn't get the arrow-functions to work, but that's most likely due to my inexperience with them.*

Comment: `.toolbar.sticky + #edit-details {padding-top:84px;}`

This did the trick.

Thanks so much for the help!